# Working from a 2017 react-router react-transition-group example where content components don't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

The demo and code => https://codesandbox.io/s/73ymn2k911

Based on my observations through dev tools, it initially knows where to place components but forgets to set `opacity: 1` or remove the old components

<s>I suspect the issue lies in app.js</s> See update below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import AnimatedSwitch from "./animated_switch";
import { firstChild } from "../utils/helpers";

import TopBar from "./top_bar";
import Home from "./home";
import Projects from "./projects";
import ProjectItem from "./project_item";
import Missed from "./missed";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projects: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    projects: json.slice(0, 7)
                });
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <TopBar />
                <Route
                    render={({ location }) => (
                        <TransitionGroup component="main">
                            <AnimatedSwitch
                                key={location.pathname}
                                location={location}
                            >
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                                <Route
                                    exact
                                    path="/projects"
                                    render={props => (
                                        <Projects {...props} projects={this.state.projects} />
                                    )}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/projects/:id"
                                    render={props => (
                                        <ProjectItem {...props} projects={this.state.projects} />
                                    )}
                                />
                                <Route component={Missed} />
                            </AnimatedSwitch>
                        </TransitionGroup>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But I could be wrong. Upon clicking a nav link on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/73ymn2k911), it prints two errors to its console that aren't reported by chrome dev tools on my live test site:

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onExited`. It will be ignored.
Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `in`.
```

This is all based on an example I found for older dependencies, posted to a blog last year. I'm trying to learn from example and it's difficult to get your head around something that changes every 6 months.

If you can help, thank you!

---

Update: I've been reviewing the react-transition-group v1 to v2 [migration guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/Migration.md#wrapping-transition-components) and I think the problem is actually my transition components which I have no idea how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this problem out for myself, but `TransitionGroup` expects it's immediate children to be of type `Transition`. The component itself does not actually do any validation on this, so it will just slap `in` and `onExit` props on all of those child nodes. Because your child in this case is a styled `div`, those properties are not valid, so you'll get those warnings. If you wrap your components in a `Transition` or `CSSTransition`, those warnings will go away.